# pgAdmin Crashing on Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I'm trying to perform the below SQL on the listed table/materialized view:

```
SELECT e.subject_id, e.hadm_id, e.icustay_id, e.itemid, e.charttime, e.value, e.valuenum
FROM MIMICIII.chartevents as e
INNER JOIN MIMICIII.adults_with_sepsis as aas1
ON aas1.subject_id = e.subject_id
INNER JOIN MIMICIII.adults_with_sepsis as aas2
ON aas2.hadm_id = e.hadm_id
```

However, pgAdmin crashes (windows error: pgAdmin has stopped responding) after about a minute of runtime. I believe the issue has to do with how pgAdmin has the chartevents stored: [image: Chart Events Structure]

I was hoping I could just perform the join on chartevents and then it would join all of the chartevents tables. As this is incorrect, how should I go about performing this join?

As well, I have provided the code for how chartevents is formed bellow.

Table:

```
                                  Table "mimiciii.chartevents_2"
    Column    |              Type              | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 row_id       | integer                        | not null  | plain    |              |
 subject_id   | integer                        | not null  | plain    |              |
 hadm_id      | integer                        |           | plain    |              |
 icustay_id   | integer                        |           | plain    |              |
 itemid       | integer                        |           | plain    |              |
 charttime    | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | plain    |              |
 storetime    | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | plain    |              |
 cgid         | integer                        |           | plain    |              |
 value        | character varying(255)         |           | extended |              |
 valuenum     | double precision               |           | plain    |              |
 valueuom     | character varying(50)          |           | extended |              |
 warning      | integer                        |           | plain    |              |
 error        | integer                        |           | plain    |              |
 resultstatus | character varying(50)          |           | extended |              |
 stopped      | character varying(50)          |           | extended |  

        |
```

Materialized View:

```
                   Materialized view "mimiciii.adults_with_sepsis"
         Column         |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
tion                                                                            -----
------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 subject_id             | integer |           | plain   |              |
 hadm_id                | integer |           | plain   |              |
 infection              | integer |           | plain   |              |
 explicit_severe_sepsis | integer |           | plain   |              |
 explicit_septic_shock  | integer |           | plain   |              |
 organ_dysfunction      | integer |           | plain   |              |
 mech_vent              | integer |           | plain   |              |
 angus                  | integer |           | plain   |              |
```

Chart Events Code:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table CHARTEVENTS
--------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CHARTEVENTS CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE CHARTEVENTS
   (    ROW_ID INT NOT NULL,
    SUBJECT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    HADM_ID INT,
    ICUSTAY_ID INT,
    ITEMID INT,
    CHARTTIME TIMESTAMP(0),
    STORETIME TIMESTAMP(0),
    CGID INT,
    VALUE VARCHAR(255),
    VALUENUM DOUBLE PRECISION,
    VALUEUOM VARCHAR(50),
    WARNING INT,
    ERROR INT,
    RESULTSTATUS VARCHAR(50),
    STOPPED VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT chartevents_rowid_pk PRIMARY KEY (ROW_ID)
  );
```

Comment: If you want to join the various chart events tables, then you will need to explicitly join them in the query.  A `UNION` might also make sense here.

Comment: Hmm, would you recommend performing the joins on the individual tables? That seems like it might be the best way to go about this. I'm confused why psql broke the table into 14 different ones.

Comment: Wait...how large is each table?

Comment: I'm using the dummy MIMICIII data. The initial .csv for `chartevents` is 79 MB (758355 rows) and `chartevents_1` has 79916 rows. The materialized view `adults_with_sepsis` has 120 rows.

Comment: Ah, chartevents is being partitioned. I'll have to use your suggestion of joining each - thanks for the help!